# Can I add style elements to semantic tags?

Tags: css, html, semantic-markup

Is it ok to add css styles to semantic elements like

```
<article style="font-size:1.2em; color:#ccc>text text </article>
```

or will this get me into trouble and should I use

```
<div style="font-size:1.2em; color:#ccc>  
<article>text text </article>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ok"? Is it valid? Sure it is. Is it a good idea? It depends entirely on your use case, but the answer is probably no regardless of the nature of the element (semantic or not - the only "non-semantic" elements are div and span).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much better to use classes rather than hard-coding styles into your HTML. This allows separation of content from presentation, and makes it much easier to make changes. So I would recommend something like

```
.article {
    font-size:1.2em; 
    color:#ccc;
}
```

and

```
<article class="article">text text </article>
```

Comment: I do use an external style sheet of course, I used this inline styles just for the sake of the example. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as its an HTML/HTML5 tag, you can definitely add classes or styles to semantic HTML elements.

You can refer below links for a list of new semantic elements in HTML5.

- https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_new_elements.asp
- http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-reference/html5-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

As long as the browser supports HTML5 tags you'll have no problem setting up your css/styles to any tags, that's the requirement of HTML5.
[More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element)

Comment: What do custom elements have to do with this?

Comment: I said custom-elements or HTML5 tags, both have the same requirements.

Comment: The question still applies. How do they have anything to do with the question?

Comment: I guess you didn't read the answer my previous comment was regarding the j08691's comment.

Comment: Praise the Lord!!

Answer (score 0):

When you use a screen reader, it will focus on the selected semantic tag. That is probably all you ever have to know in terms of how these semantics tags are being used.

Having said that, it wouldn't make sense to add margins as you typically want to focus directly on the content. But other styles are perfectly fine. Even padding is okay as long as you don't use them as an alternative to margins.